# Persistent background page on demand or an event page that doesn't unload?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to build a extension that behaves like a timer. It should count down the seconds when activated, but should do nothing with inactive.

The [`chrome.alarms`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/alarms) API is interesting, but does not have enough precision nor granularity. It only fires at most once per minute, and it may fire late. If I want something to execute more often than that, I can't use this API.

Then, the next natural solution is to use a [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) and use `setTimeout` or `setInterval` in there. However, background pages are persistent, and they take up resources (e.g. memory) even when idle. So they are not ideal.

The best solution seems to be an [event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) to run the timer. However, the documentation says:

> Once it has been loaded, **the event page will stay running as long as it is active** (for example, calling an extension API or issuing a network request).
>
> […]
>
> Once the event page has been idle a short time (a few seconds), the runtime.onSuspend event is dispatched. The event page has a few more seconds to handle this event before it is forcibly unloaded.
>
> […]
>
> If your extension uses `window.setTimeout()` or `window.setInterval()`, switch to using the alarms API instead. DOM-based timers won't be honored if the event page shuts down.

Unfortunately, having an active `setInterval` is not enough to consider an event page active. In fact, from my tests, an interval up to 10 seconds is short enough to keep the event page running, but anything greater than 10 or 15 seconds is too far apart and the event page will get unloaded. I've tested this on [my crx-reload-tab project](https://github.com/denilsonsa/crx-reload-tab).

---

I believe what I want is a middle ground:

- **I want a background page that I can load and unload on demand**. (Instead of one that keeps loaded all the time.)
- **I want an event page that stays persistent in memory for as long as I say**; but otherwise could be unloaded. (Instead of one that gets unloaded automatically by the browser.)

Is it possible? How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Background pages cannot be unloaded on demand, and Chrome decides Event page lifecycle for you (there is nothing you can do in `onSuspend` to prevent it).

---

If your concern is timers, you could try my solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34287377/934239), which basically splits a timer into shorter timers for a "sparse" busy-wait. That's enough to keep the event page loaded and is a viable solution if you don't need to do that frequently.

---

In general, there are some things that will keep an event page loaded:

> If you're using message passing, be sure to close unused message ports. The event page will not shut down until all message ports are closed.

This can be exploited if you have any other context to keep an open `Port` to, for example a content script. See [Long-lived connections docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#connect) for more details.

---

In practice, if you often or constantly need precise, sub-minute timers, an Event page is a bad solution. Your resource gains from using one might not justify it.

Comment: I remember I tried leaving an open `Port`, but I had no other context open, so it wasn't enough to keep the event page active. It seems we both agreed on the workaround/solution of keeping a short timeout/interval just to keep the event page active. A *sparse busy-wait loop*, as you called it. Thanks!

Comment: Looping with setInterval alone did not prevent suspending for me. Perhaps the implementation has become more strict.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in Xan's answer we can abuse messaging. There's nothing wrong about it either in case you want to **temporarily** prevent the event page from unloading. For example while displaying a progress meter using chrome.notifications API or any other activity based on setTimeout/setInterval that may exceed the default unload timeout which is 5-15 seconds.

#### Demo

It creates an iframe in the background page and the iframe connects to the background page. In addition to manifest.json and a background script you'll need to make two additional files bg-iframe.html and bg-iframe.js with the code specified below.

**manifest.json** excerpt:

```js
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["bg.js"],
    "persistent": false
  }
```

**bg.js:**

```js
function preventUnload() {
  let iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
  if (!iframe) {
    iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    document.body.appendChild(iframe).src = 'bg-iframe.html';
  }
}

function allowUnload() {
  let iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
  if (iframe) iframe.remove();
}

chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(() => {});
```

**bg-iframe.html:**

```html
<script src="bg-iframe.js"></script>
```

**bg-iframe.js:**

```js
chrome.runtime.connect();
```

**Usage example in bg.js:**

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (message === 'start') doSomething();
});

function doSomething() {
  preventUnload();
  // do something asynchronous that's spread over time
  // like for example consecutive setTimeout or setInterval calls
  let ticks = 20;
  const interval = setInterval(tick, 1000);

  function tick() {
    // do something
    // ................
    if (--ticks <= 0) done();
  }

  function done() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    allowUnload();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this function:

```
function _doNotSleep() {
    if (isActive) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            fetch(chrome.runtime.getURL('manifest.json'));
            _doNotSleep();
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

But the problem with such approach is that Devtools network tab polluted with this http stub.

Comment: chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(callback) seemed to work for refreshing the activity timeout.