# Start a background thread when clicking button in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a chrome extension where a background task will be started when the user clicks a button. The task will regularly send a GET request to check some variable. Then the user can stop the task by clicking another button.

This is the first time I work with chrome extension, so the first idea was to use web workers, but it seems that [Chrome does not allow loading local files for workers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21408510/chrome-cant-load-web-worker).

Is there another way to do it ?

Comment: You need a [background script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages). See also the [overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview).

Comment: @wOxxOm as I understood, background script is for the page event listeners. What I am looking for is like a webworker, a kind of thread executing in the background, triggered by a button in the popup, and stopped with another button.

Comment: @wOxxOm can you explain how would you do it ?

Comment: In short, the popup will send a message, your background script will receive it in [onMessage listener](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging). The background script runs in a hidden separate background page where you can do your stuff, spawn web workers if needed, anything. If you declare the background script with `"persistent":false` see also [Persistent background page on demand or an event page that doesn't unload?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58577052)

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you. I am getting to the same problem, webworkers are not anymore allowed with chrome extension, and executing a code with an infinite loop blocks the popup.

Comment: Web workers are perfectly allowed in chrome extensions, you simply need to use a script that's inside the extension directory. It won't be a `file` URL. It'll be a path e.g.  `/script.js`

Comment: Also, depending on the goal, you can do everything in the background script, without any workers.