# JavaScript functions setTimeout() and setInterval() are sometimes not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

My own Google Chrome extension stops working after some time, because setTimeout() is not working in some cases.

Therefore the background script is not sending a message to the content script after some necessary delay.

I have found this problem by writing many console.log() statements.

**As a solution i thought about using setInterval() until the message is sent to the content script:**

```
var timer = setInterval(function() {
  clearInterval(timer);
  // Sending a message to the content script
}, 3000);
```

My code before, during and after setInterval() is quiet long, so i hope this code snippet is somehow enough.

**Does anyone know in which cases these Timeouts or Intervals do not start?**

**Or are there any similar options i could use?**

I have thought about using the Chrome Alarms API instead, but alarms can only be used once every minute and the minimum delay is one minute if i am not mistaken.

Comment: That’s an odd usage of setInterval. Anyway, perhaps the “stops working” is related to _other_ code?

Comment: If you declared the background script with `"persistent":false`, this is the correct and expected behavior: the background script will unload on inactivity ignoring any timers. See [Persistent background page on demand or an event page that doesn't unload?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37017209)

Answer (score -1):

I never experienced any issue of setinterval or settimeout stops working. I guess there might be an issue in your code. If you are sure about the bug you should make a demo project and report bug on github.